# Restore the original task manager after replacing it with the Sysinternals process explorer

Tags: task-manager, sysinternals

After replacing the default Windows task manager with [Sysinternals’](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) process explorer via the `Options → Replace task manager` menu, how do you undo that action, i.e. restore the original task manager? **I’ve already tried clicking that menu again, but it doesn’t do anything.**

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Delete the subkey `Debugger` of the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe`.

In `cmd`, you can accomplish this by running (as admin): `reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe" /v Debugger`.

Comment: the answer is almost perfect, just add that you need to run cmd as admin

Comment: According to the help documentation it's meant to change to "Restore Task Manager" but there must be a bug which doesn't correctly detect which state its in.

Comment: Don't delete the whole key, just delete the `Debugger` string value.

Comment: Yes, this worked fine in v16.12. It was not a "Restore Task Manager" but it had a checkmark like the other entries and was uncheckable. Now with new Laptop I installed lates v16.32 and there the menu entry does not behave correctly anymore. :-(

Comment: Actually it is a bug in the 64-bit version. Starting the 32-bit version the menu entry behaves as it should, so you can use the 32-bit version to first make it the default and then restore the vanilla one. I guess there is some string comparison that does not consider the changed name for the 64-bit executable.

Comment: Actually after renaming `procexp.exe` to `procexp32.exe` and `procexp64.exe` to `procexp.exe` it behaved like expected which sounds like I was right. But actually then renaming the files back and using `procexp64.exe` still behaves correctly, so somehow this playing around worked-around the problem somehow it seems.

Comment: As @JakeEdwards noted, just the Button label is not updated. Click on "Replace Task Manager" again, and it will be removed.

Answer (score 6):

maybe they fixed that in the latest versions?

ugh another post in microsoft forums suggests to

1. run procexp.exe (the 32-bit version, not procexp64.exe), choose Options -> Replace Task Manager there
2. close it
3. call task manager, so the 32-bit procexp is opened, and go to Options -> Restore Task Manager.

I am on Windows 10
Now I didn't see that happen, 32-bit procexp still writes "Replace Task Manager"
But if I open procexp.exe **as Administrator** there is a tick sign instead of a Shield sign next to Replace Task Manager -> I press on the tick sign, the tick goes away.

I tried to do the above with 64-bit version and it worked too - it's just that instead of a tick sign there's always a shield.

oh whatever.

Comment: manually opening procexp.exe worked for me as described

Answer (score 2):

We can accomplish this using PowerShell:

```powershell
# Restore taskmgr.exe as Task Manager
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe\" -Name 'Debugger' 

# Check if PROCEXP64.EXE is still Task Manager
if($null -eq (Get-ItemProperty  -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe\" -ErrorAction  SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Debugger' -ErrorAction Stop)) { 
    Write-Host "taskmgr.exe successfully restored as Task Manager"
}
```